# How to find the column that does not contain a certain value?

Tags: r

I have a matrix that looks like this:

```
     1   2   3   4   5   6
  1  0.4 0.5 0.1 0.3 0.3 0.7
  2  0.1 0.1 0.8 0.7 0.7 0.4
  3  0.6 0.2 0.3 0.1 0.1 0.9
```

I want to find the column that does not contain `0.1`, which is column `6`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are couple of base R options -

```
#1. Using colSums
names(df)[colSums(df == 0.1) == 0]
#[1] "6"

#2. Using Filter
names(Filter(function(x) !any(x == 0.1), df))
#[1] "6"
```

We can also use `purrr` -

```
#3. keep
names(purrr::keep(df, ~!any(.x == 0.1)))

#4. discard
names(purrr::discard(df, ~any(.x == 0.1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `select` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   select(where(~ !0.1 %in% .)) %>%
   names
```

-output

```
[1] "X6"
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(X1 = c(0.4, 0.1, 0.6), X2 = c(0.5, 0.1, 0.2), 
    X3 = c(0.1, 0.8, 0.3), X4 = c(0.3, 0.7, 0.1), X5 = c(0.3, 
    0.7, 0.1), X6 = c(0.7, 0.4, 0.9)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3"))
```